# ATTiny814 not going into powerdown sleep

Tags: sleep, sleep-mode, attiny

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <avr/cpufunc.h>
#include "timers.h"
#include <util/delay.h>

#include <Arduino.h>
#include "avr/sleep.h"
#include "avr/wdt.h"
#include "Wire.h"

void RTC_init(void);
void LED0_init(void);
inline void LED0_toggle(void);
void SLPCTRL_init(void);

//uint8_t wakeup = 0;
volatile uint8_t flash = 0;
void RTC_init(void)
{
    /* Initialize RTC: */
    while (RTC.STATUS > 0)
    {
        ; /* Wait for all register to be synchronized */
    }

    /* 32.768kHz External Crystal Oscillator (XOSC32K) */
    RTC.CLKSEL = RTC_CLKSEL_INT1K_gc; /*ULP Clock oscillator is being used*/

    /* Run in debug: enabled */
    RTC.DBGCTRL = RTC_DBGRUN_bm;
    
    RTC.PITINTCTRL = RTC_PI_bm; /* Periodic Interrupt: enabled */
    
    RTC.PITCTRLA = (RTC_PERIOD_CYC32768_gc) /* RTC Clock Cycles 32768 */
                 | (RTC_PITEN_bm); /* Enable: enabled */    
}

void LED0_init(void)
{
    /* Make High (OFF) */
    PORTB.OUT |= PIN1_bm;
    /* Make output */
    PORTB.DIR |= PIN1_bm;
}


ISR(RTC_PIT_vect)
{
    /* Clear flag by writing '1': */
    RTC.PITINTFLAGS = RTC_PI_bm;
    
    flash = 1;

}

void SLPCTRL_init(void)
{
    SLPCTRL.CTRLA |= SLPCTRL_SMODE_PDOWN_gc;
    SLPCTRL.CTRLA |= SLPCTRL_SEN_bm;
}

int main(void)
{
    LED0_init();
    RTC_init();
    SLPCTRL_init();
    //(&PORTA.PIN0CTRL)[0];
    for (uint8_t pin=7; pin<=1; pin--) 
        (&PORTA.PIN0CTRL)[pin] = PORT_ISC_INPUT_DISABLE_gc;
    
    PORTB.PIN0CTRL = PORT_ISC_INPUT_DISABLE_gc;
    PORTB.PIN1CTRL = PORT_ISC_INPUT_DISABLE_gc;
    PORTB.PIN2CTRL = PORT_ISC_INPUT_DISABLE_gc;
    PORTB.PIN3CTRL = PORT_ISC_INPUT_DISABLE_gc;
    
    /* Enable Global Interrupts */
    sei();
    
    while (1) 
    {
        /* Put the CPU in sleep */
        sleep_cpu();
        if(flash == 1)
        {
            PORTB.OUTTGL |= PIN1_bm;
            _delay_ms(5000);
            PORTB.OUTTGL |= PIN1_bm;
        }

    }
}
```

ATTiny814 is not going into power down sleep mode. This was working a few days back I haven't changed anything. When it was working the device was consuming 0.6uA in sleep mode and 1.874 mA when green led flashed. After a few days when I flashed the firmware again. The ATTiny814 is now consuming 32uA in sleep mode and 1.872 mA when green led flashes.

I have tried enable the disabling the sleep mode before and after the sleep_cpu instruction. But still no response.

Do comment if you guys have experienced this before.